# What is the difference between Google's breakpad and crashpad libraries?

Tags: minidump, google-breakpad

They both are crashing report libraries that generates minidump for developer analyzing, and both are developed by Google's Chromium project:

[breakpad](https://github.com/google/breakpad)

[crashpad](https://github.com/chromium/crashpad)

Any difference in their intended use cases?

Comment: Crashpad is newer and I think was planned with better support for some newer platforms. Breakpad is used by a number of large Open Source projects on Windows, Linux and Mac (possibly also on Android), e.g. Mozilla Firefox, Chromium (not all platforms), LibreOffice (only Windows and Linux). The last time I looked deeper into it (2016) breakpad was more mature at least for desktop use cases but I had the feeling that crashpad was more actively developed.

Comment: @moggi Please post answers as answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

| / | Breakpad | Crashpad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OSX-10.10+/in-process | ✅ | ✅ |
| OSX-10.10+/out-process | ❌ | ✅ |

| / | Breakpad | Crashpad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iOS-5.0+/in-process | ✅ | ✅ |
| tvOS/in-process | ✅ | ❌ |
| watchOS/in-process | ✅ | ❌ |

- https://github.com/google/breakpad/blob/1147c2fcf09cf150e6d7891e94bd390c6c8a9def/src/client/ios/exception_handler_no_mach.cc#L37-L41
- https://github.com/google/breakpad/blob/1147c2fcf09cf150e6d7891e94bd390c6c8a9def/src/client/ios/Breakpad.mm#L50-L54
- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/crashpad-dev/c/SSq9CriDJGo

---

Reply to @Lindeijer

> See also the note in [Breakpads documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/guides/breakpad/):
>
> > As opposed to Crashpad, Breakpad uses in-process crash reporting. This is less robust and has several disadvantages over out-of-process crash reporting. Unless you have integrated Breakpad already, we strongly recommend you to consider using Crashpad instead.

It is doc of `Sentry`, not doc of `Breakpad`

Actually `Breakpad` supports in-process and out-process on Windows/Linux/MacOSX(pre-10.10), according to https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/+/master/docs/exception_handling.md

Comment: If you're going to make a reply, please make a comment on my answer. Now I've noticed your answer by accident, 3 years after you wrote it. :-) You're correct, the linked docs are for using Breakpad with Sentry. But I never stated in my answer that Breakpad did not support out-of-progress crash reporting, only that it couldn't do this on macOS 10.10+.

Comment: Ah, so the text I quoted did say this. Maybe that applies only to usage of Breakpad with Sentry. I've made some small corrections, in any case. Also, whoops, not 3 years later... I misread "Sep 18" as being September 2018!

Comment: Sorry. I didn't have enough credits to comment until now

Answer (score 9):

See [the Crashpad announcement](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/6eouc7q2j_g) for the reasons why it was developed.

The major difference with Breakpad appears to be that Crashpad enables out-of-process crash reporting also for Mac OS X 10.10 and newer, which Breakpads design could not support.

See also the note in [Sentrys Breakpad documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/breakpad/):

> Breakpad uses in-process crash reporting, which is less robust and has several disadvantages over out-of-process crash reporting.

(which may be only really true for macOS 10.10+)